# How to insert a Picture Object from Json Datasource to List & Label report

Tags: json, report, reporting, listlabel

I use List & Label to generate various reports from database content. The output is handeled by a middleware service which receives the data as Json payload.

Up to now I did not manage to display images/pictures in reports such as i.e. an Itempicture on a customer quotation.

Does anyone may know, which graphic format is expected by the report designer picture object and/or which function might have to be used?

`Drawing({String})` expects a path to a physical image file -> hence can not use it because the image data is available as kind of raw image text.

Any help ist highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It will work, if you handle this points:

- the field within the JSON need to be base64 encoded - you can get it like this:

```
using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var picture = new Bitmap(<YOURPIC>))
    {
        picture.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(memory.GetBuffer());
    }
}
```

- use the [AutoDefineField-Event](https://docu.combit.net/net/en/combit.ListLabel%7Ecombit.Reporting.ListLabel%7EAutoDefineField_EV.html) of the List & Label object and override FieldType for the matching picture field with its base64 content to LlFieldType.Drawing - e.g.:

```
private void LL_AutoDefineField(object sender, AutoDefineElementEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Name == "Contacts.myPic")
    {
        e.FieldType = LlFieldType.Drawing;
    }
}
```